# cannot set readonly property:params

Tags: grails, parameters

i'm trying to save a picture and return it's visit-url，but system throw a exception about params: 'cannot set readonly property: params'

```
def upload() {
    def attachmentInstance = new Attachment(utype:params.type, udata:params.data)
    if (!attachmentInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [attachmentInstance: attachmentInstance])
        return
    }

    def subMap = [url:"${createLink(controller:'attachment', action:'renderImg', params:'[id:${attachmentInstance.id}]')}", width:0, height:0]

    def jsonMap = [id:attachmentInstance.id, type:"image", thumbnail:"", data:subMap]

    def result = [result:jsonMap]

    render result as JSON
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can nest your GStrings as you have with the `def subMap` line. `${createLink...` contains another `${}`. I've had this issue in the past and I think you have to store the second `${}` in a variable and then reference the variable instead (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a little over-complex, can you try:

```
def subMap = [url:createLink(controller:'attachment', action:'renderImg', params:[id:attachmentInstance.id]), width:0, height:0]
```